# Sort firebase data base on child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating simple application with firebase. My firebase database structure is look like this,

```
user:{ 
   uid:{ 
      name:user1,
      age:22,
      score:80,
      address:mycity,
      uid:uid
   }
},

contact:{ 
   uid:{ 
      phone:123456
   }
}
```

And this is my database reference code.

```
mRef = db.getInstance().getReference("user");

mRef.orderByChild("city").equalTo(mycity)
 .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener {


   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

     HashMap < String, String > hashmap = new HashMap < > ();

     hashmap.put("name", snapshot.child("name").getValue());
     hashmap.put("score", snapshot.child("score").getValue());

     userarr.add(hashmap);

     contact = db.getInstance().getReference("contact").child(snapshot.child("uid").getValue());

     contact.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener {

      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       contactHashmap.put("phoneNumber", dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue());

       contactarr.add(contactHashmap);

      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}

     });


     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}

    });

  }
 }
```

I want to sort data by "score". If I sort it with "Comparator" in client side . Two arraylist data cannot be matched . How to sort data by "score".

Sorry for my bad English speaking.

Edit: I want to get user base on same region(address). And sort them base on "score" .(either ascending or descending)

Comment: Can you please clear your requirements and what is the problem you faced?

Comment: Did you try `mRef.orderByChild("score")` on **user** database reference?

Comment: What do you mean sort? You want to get the users from the database based on the `score` property?

Comment: I want to get user from same region(address). And sort them base on "score".

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
// Sort by score
Query myTopScoreQuery = databaseReference.child("user").child(mycity).orderByChild("score");
myTopScoreQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});
```

Or

```
// Sort by score
Query myTopScoreQuery = databaseReference.child("user").child(mycity).orderByChild("uid/score");
myTopScoreQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});
```

Comment: But I want to get user based on same address and sort retrived user ascending based on their score.

Comment: Did you try above solution? And what was happening after that?

Comment: if  "databaseReference" is on "user" like this,    `DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");`    , I can't get users  based on same address. It query all users based on score. Where should `databaseReference` be on?

Comment: If you check my answer, I have pointed child on DB ref. Try mine one and check output

Comment: Yeah, I have tried . It gives users base on score. But it shows all users instead of users from my region.